# Annualization of coskewness and cokurtosis

Tags: modern-portfolio-theory, portfolio-optimization, skewness, kurtosis, annualized

I am constructing a mean-variance-skewness-kurtosis portfolio based on monthly data with a holding period of one year. [Meucci](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1635484) describes how to annualize higher order moments in general, but not how to do it for co-moments such as the coskewness and cokurtosis matrix. Please enlighten me.